# Set User-Agent when using RequestBuilder?

Tags: gwt

I'm using RequestBuilder, is there a way to set the User-Agent header? I'm trying:

```
RequestBuilder request = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, url);
request.setHeader("User-Agent", "myuseragent");
```

but not sure if that is correct, does the browser overwrite this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User-Agent` is a reserved header that you're not allowed to set:

http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader()-method